# How large were CFC emissions per year before the Montreal Protocol came into practice?

Tags: climate-change, climate, ozone

This article [The China CFC dilemma](https://www.chemistryworld.com/opinion/the-china-cfc-dilemma/3009280.article?fbclid=IwAR1s-kHINmv4SZYm7-qL3A1uqsjWftYRIP8e8zwBqQ5C7IzF8RV2i-1-yfY) states CFC emissions now might be 67,000 tonnes per year. I tried to look for how large were the emissions of it before the Montreal Protocol but I couldnt find it.  How large were CFC emissions per year before the Montreal Protocol came into practice? Were they much larger than today's ?

Comment: These articles might be of interest to you: [*How we traced ‘mystery emissions’ of CFCs back to eastern China*](https://theconversation.com/how-we-traced-mystery-emissions-of-cfcs-back-to-eastern-china-117545) & [*China feels the heat over rogue CFC emissions*](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-02109-2)

Comment: There is a nice article on [Our World In Data](https://ourworldindata.org) with a bunch of time series: [Ozone Layer](https://ourworldindata.org/ozone-layer).